# Could the 5:4 aspect ratio of my monitor affect videogames performance?

Tags: performance, graphics-card

For starters I would like to mention my PC's specs:

- OS: Windows 7 64 bit
- CPU: AMD FX 6350 3.9GHz
- RAM: Dual Channel 6GB 1333MHz
- HDD: 500GB SATA III
- MOBO: ASUS M5A97 R2.0
- GPU: Radeon HD 6750

I have always had to play modern games in the lowest/low settings to get a moderate (not high) performance. What modern games? Red Orchestra 2/Rising Storm, ArmA 2, Natural Selection 2 and most recently Payday 2.

My Monitor is a Viewsonic VG930m. Commonly running at 1280x1024, however, when I want to play games I usually have to lower my resolution to 1024x768 and graphics to lowest settings (this is the case with Payday 2 and I feel like going 800x600 because it still kinda slows).

I asked my friend how his laptop performs with Payday 2 and he says it performs just fine with the default settings. His laptop has Intel HD Graphics and I'm really wondering how my PC is performing lower even having a dedicated GPU and much better CPU.

And so I was thinking that perhaps modern games are coded and optimized for today's standard aspect ratio 16:9 and perform worse when having to adjust to my monitors' aspect ratio. Could this be the case? Am I missing something else here? Any information is appreciated.

Thanks for reading and looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Aspect ratio shouldn't matter, but make sure you disable anti-aliasing and other expensive things (shadows, reflections) as your first option, before lowering resolution.  Also, does your friend's laptop use the nVidia Optimus setup?  It might be switching to the better gpu when games launch.

Comment: All settings are low/lowest/off. You name it, anti-aliasing, shadows, reflections. Everything off. And no, his laptop has no GPU other than the IGP Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: Other questions: What OS, and is it 32 or 64 bit?  Vsync off?  And what is your performance symptom (low overall framerate or periodic "hitching", or slow load times?)

Comment: Sorry should've specified that in the question. Will edit it in a moment. Windows 7 64 bit. V-Sync off. Low overall framerate. Slow load times is kinda there but manageable. And, particular to Payday 2, animations skipping frames. Like if they were at 6 FPS but everything else going at ~25.

Comment: My gut feeling is GPU bottleneck but that card is recent enough that this seems odd.  Long shot, but maybe your card isn't getting enough juice.  Make sure the direct connection from the power supply to the card is secure and possibly run diagnostics to see if it's under-voltage.  Software could also drop the video clock rate if it is overheating.

Comment: It's not that long of a shot actually. I recently changed the case and I had trouble getting the MOBO to sit correctly and what not. Do you know of any software I can use to run diagnostics on my GPU?

Comment: Chances are extremely good your ram is the bottleneck.  6GB is not a ton at all for Windows 7 and modern games to run concurrently.  And if your hard drive is full, your paging will also not work properly.  Aspect ratio means nothing but the number of pixels it has to render.

Comment: RAM is ok, it very rarely goes above using 3GB when running any resource-intensive game (I actually used to have 4 and it was the same). You got a point in the HDD tho, I'll clean it up later. I know aspect radio has nothing to do but I was just wondering if the devs code for a certain aspect ratio in mind. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Maybe double check that all fans are working correctly and everything is dust-free? The hardware spec looks fine especially for a relatively low pixel count @ 1280x1024, so I'm wondering if it's throttling down for thermal reasons.